# Squid returns 400 to GET / HTTP/1.1 and Host Header

Tags: proxy, http, squid

I need to demonstrate and test a Squid setup, which should blacklist by default, and allow requests only to whitelisted URLs from known networks.  This is currently running in my staging environment, and is working as expected, but I want to test and demo it on demand, with nicer feedback than with curl.

I've deployed Redbot (https://github.com/mnot/redbot), which I've set up to send all HTTP requests via the Squid proxy

Using `curl -x` from the Redbot machine, all my tests pass, but using the application, Squid returns a 400 whatever happens.  All requests go to Squid, and I see every request, but instead of returning a 403 and `X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0`, or allowing the request, every request gets a 400, and `X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0`.

Digging into it - logs and tcpdump - the key difference I see is that
Redbot sends a request of the form:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: chess.com
```

Curl sends:

```
GET http://chess.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: chess.com
```

From the RFC it seems like Redbot's request is perfectly valid, and so
I feel like Squid should do the right thing and deduce from the host
header what Redbot wants, and go through its ACLs.  However, it just
errors with:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: squid/3.5.27
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 23 Apr 2018 11:50:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3465
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0
X-Cache: MISS from proxy.redaction.com
Via: 1.1 proxy.redaction.com (squid/3.5.27)
```

Does this seem like a Squid config issue? Or do I need to make Redbot
make a request like Curl does?

**Update:**

Adding `intercept` to the `http_port` directive has resulted in the Host header making its way into the URL, but now Squid gives a 403, even when the ACL should permit it:

```
z1524498993.558      0 10.8.0.33 TCP_MISS/403 3985 GET
http://www.openstreetmap.com/ - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1524498993.559      0 10.8.2.19 TCP_MISS/403 4077 GET
http://www.openstreetmap.com/ - ORIGINAL_DST/10.8.0.33 text/html


acl cluster src 10.8.0.0/16
acl streetmap dstdomain .openstreetmap.com
http_access allow cluster streetmap
http_access deny all
```

Comment: How did you solve it?